# Machine Learning Approach needed: Predict most likely feature value given all other features in a feature vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am in need of a suitable machine learning approach that will tell me the most likely value for a feature in a feature vector given the combination of the other features in that vector (and the knowledge acquired from the training set). My feature vectors can contain several thousand features. However, only very few feature combinations are really likely to occur.  I want the classifier to learn these plausible combinations.

Toy Example: If my training vectors are (0,1,2), (1,1,2), (2,2,2) then the classifier should predict that for an unknown item (3,1,x) the most likely value for x is '2'.

Note that the classifier should be able to make such predictions for every feature in the vector given the (n-1) values of the other features in that vector.

I already experimented with a Naive Bayes Classifier ... but this only tells me the most likely category for a given feature vector ... not the likely value of a particular feature in the incoming feature vector.

Could anyone please suggest a suitable method that will do this for me? Ideally with a reference to a suitable package in Python?

Thanks and kind regards -

Pat

Comment: This question would have better luck at http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what's available to you in [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html). What you're looking for is anything with the word "regression" in it (as apposed to classification). I would start with just linear regression as your base line and depending on what computation you can afford try out some of the other regression techniques.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback ... this is an excellent reference with lots of material to dive into. Thank you so much! This was very helpful.

Comment: support vector machine